# Need Pagination when I use Multiple ng-repeat in a Table?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pagination

Here is the Code for the Pagination,I tried with dir-pagination,Please check

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>                
                <th>Level S No</th>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <!--<th>Mobile</th>-->
                <th>Referral ID</th>
                <th>Referral Name</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="unilvl in Levels track by unilvl.lvl">
                <tr ng-repeat="UnilvlPrintView in Levels | filter:{lvl:unilvl.lvl}:true  track by UnilvlPrintView.lvl">
                    <td colspan="8" class="active" style="color: #de1b2a;text-align:left"> Level - {{UnilvlPrintView.lvl}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="UnilvlPrintView in UniLevelPrintView | filter:{lvl:unilvl.lvl} track by $index">
                    <td class="label-center">{{UnilvlPrintView.lvlsno}}</td>
                    <td class="label-center">{{UnilvlPrintView.idno}}</td>
                    <td class="label-left">{{UnilvlPrintView.name}}</td>
                    <td class="label-left">{{UnilvlPrintView.city}}</td>
                    <!--<td class="label-center">{{UnilvlPrintView.Mobile}}</td>-->
                    <td class="label-center">{{UnilvlPrintView.sponser}}</td>
                    <td class="label-left">{{UnilvlPrintView.sponsername}}</td>
                    <td class="label-center">{{UnilvlPrintView.doj}}</td>
                    <td class="label-center">{{UnilvlPrintView.status}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried with

```
      <dir-pagination-controls max-size="15" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true">
       </dir-pagination-controls>
```

How can I Apply Pagination using Angular js ?Please Help me